# Python check if values of a dataframe are present in another dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two dataframes. I want to drop the values in first dataframe (default) after comparing with second dataframe (provided by user)

```
def_df = pd.DataFrame([['alpha','beta'],['gamma','delta']],index=['ab_plot',gd_plot])

               0    1
ab_plot     alpha   beta
gd_plot     gamma   delta
rk_plot     ray     kite


user_df = pd.DataFrame([10,20],index=['alpha','beta'])

        0
alpha   10
beta    20
```

## I want to compare two dataframes and know the possible plots for given user data.

Expected answer

```
['ab_plot'] # since user has provided data for `'alpha','beta'`
```

My approach:

```
posble_plots_with_user_data = [True for x in posble_plots.values if x in df.columns]
```

Present answer:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need test all values if match at least one value by index from `user_df` use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter `def_df.index`:

```
#changed data
def_df = pd.DataFrame([['alpha','beta'],['gamma','beta']],index=['ab_plot','gd_plot'])

user_df = pd.DataFrame([10,20],index=['alpha','beta'])

posble_plots_with_user_data = def_df.index[def_df.isin(user_df.index).any(axis=1)].tolist()
print (posble_plots_with_user_data)
['ab_plot', 'gd_plot']
```

If need rows with match all values per rows use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
posble_plots_with_user_data = def_df.index[def_df.isin(user_df.index).all(axis=1)].tolist()
print (posble_plots_with_user_data)
['ab_plot']
```

**Details**:

```
print (def_df.isin(user_df.index))
             0     1
ab_plot   True  True
gd_plot  False  True
```